# Перенаправление на страницу с текстом ошибки

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-webforms

Доброго времени суток всем. Есть веб-приложение на asp.net. В web.config переопределен тег <customErrors>:

**<custom Errors defaultRedirect="http://MyServer/MyApplicationName/ErrorStatus.htm" mode="On">**

Перенаправление отрабатывает, все ок. Вопрос заключается в следующем: как на этой странице вывести текст возникшей ошибки? Буду благодарен любому ответу или ссылке на соответствующую тему/материал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы записать текст в статический файл HTML его нужно создавать динамически, что не очень хороший вариант. Лучше использовать aspx страницы. Но в целом я вообще подобное не советую. Испоьзуйте эту самую страницу с обобщённым сведением об ошибке. Детали нужно логировать и делать приватными.

Comment: спасибо, согласен, буду использовать логирование.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно стоит попробовать [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror.aspx)

Comment: Вариант. Спасибо.